# VXR Issue (Won't accelerate)

Tags: engine

I have a 2007 VXR, I have owned it for 2 months. 5 Days ago when driving home from work the car lost all power and there was a lot of shaking, I stopped the engine and restarted it, also the engine management light started to flash. I took it to a mechanic a couple of days ago, he told me that there was 3 error codes 42001 which was too much emissions, but the previous owner de-catted the car, so that is why. The other two was p300 and p303. He said that is was random misfire of the third cylinder and to take the coil pack off to see if the spark plugs were oily and that if they weren't it was just a coil pack, I removed the coil pack and the plugs were clean, so I replaced the coil pack, but after 10 minutes of driving like before the car would slow down and struggle to accelerate. So it is not the head gasket, or the coil pack, also the day after the car first had trouble there was a lot of white smoke, but I have not seen this since, also on one occasion there was an error code for the o2 sensor, but that has not come up again since. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: VXR? You need to find out whether the cylinder is losing fuel spark or compression. You say that you replaced the coil but is the coil  (assuming COP with a built in transistor) power supply, trigger  and ground OK? Are any other cylinders misfiring or is it just the one? Are the injectors  and wiring OK? If you do a running compression test does it lose compression as the misfire begins? How about engine vacuum? Does the car have cylinder deactivation?